# Conditional plot according to a string value in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have datasets like this:

```
   5.00  0.29490912E-08 CLOSE ENC          
   6.00  0.23846514E-08 CLOSE ENC          
   7.00  0.19817730E-08 CLOSE ENC          
   8.00  0.16799040E-08 CLOSE ENC          
   9.00  0.14454043E-08 CLOSE ENC          
  10.00  0.12580897E-08 CLOSE ENC          
  11.00  0.11051156E-08 CLOSE ENC          
  12.00  0.97791894E-09 CLOSE ENC          
  13.00  0.87057114E-09           
  14.00  0.77883753E-09           
  15.00  0.69961252E-09           
  16.00  0.63056681E-09                    
  17.00  0.56991906E-09                    
  18.00  0.51628366E-09                    
  19.00  0.46856659E-09                    
  20.00  0.42589251E-09                    
  21.00  0.38755271E-09 FAR ENC                   
  22.00  0.35296719E-09 FAR ENC           
  23.00  0.32165672E-09 FAR ENC
```

As you can see some times there are 3 data in a line (2 numbers and a string) and some times only 2 numbers. I want to know if it is possible to skip the data point when the 3rd value is the string `"CLOSE ENC"`.
I have tried this:

```
plot "inputfile.dat" u 1:(trim(strcol(3)) ne "CLOSE ENC" ? $2 : NaN)
```

but it doesn't work.

The error message is:

```
gnuplot> plot "inputfile.dat" u 1:(trim(strcol(3)) ne "CLOSE ENC" ? $2 : NaN) 
                                                                              
^

"Ploter.plt" line 14: x range is invalid
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Problem solved? Any response would be polite and appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to cleanly (without warnings) handle the varying number of columns, so I resort to this:

```
plot '<grep -v "CLOSE ENC" inputfile.dat' using 1:2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a "classical" data filter question, however, with the difficulty that the filter column might not exist, which requires a different approach.
If you are working with Linux you have the tool `grep` which makes it a one-liner as the answer of @Armali shows.
If you want to have a platform independent gnuplot-only solution, you have to spend a few more lines. The assumption here is that the column separator of the original data is whitespace.

However, this will plot the full x-range of your data. If you want to filter your x-range automatically as well, you can use the following slightly more complicated plotting line:

```
plot $Data u (y=myFilter(2,3,"CLOSE"),y==y? real(myStrCol(1)):NaN):(y) w lp pt 7 notitle
```

Maybe there are even simpler *gnuplot-only* solutions.

**Code:**

```
### conditional plot (with missing column)
reset session

$Data <<EOD
5.00 0.29490912E-08 CLOSE ENC
6.00 0.23846514E-08 CLOSE ENC
7.00 0.19817730E-08 CLOSE ENC
8.00 0.16799040E-08 CLOSE ENC
9.00 0.14454043E-08 CLOSE ENC
10.00 0.12580897E-08 CLOSE ENC
11.00 0.11051156E-08 CLOSE ENC
12.00 0.97791894E-09 CLOSE ENC
13.00 0.87057114E-09
14.00 0.77883753E-09
15.00 0.69961252E-09
16.00 0.63056681E-09
17.00 0.56991906E-09
18.00 0.51628366E-09
19.00 0.46856659E-09
20.00 0.42589251E-09
21.00 0.38755271E-09 FAR ENC
22.00 0.35296719E-09 FAR ENC
23.00 0.32165672E-09 FAR ENC
EOD

set datafile separator "\n"
myStrCol(col) = word(strcol(1),col)
myFilter(colD,colF,Fvalue) = myStrCol(colF) eq Fvalue ? NaN : real(myStrCol(colD))

plot $Data u (real(myStrCol(1))):(myFilter(2,3,"CLOSE")) w lp pt 7 notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]